# Load symbols from other binaries

Tags: c, dynamic-loading

I'm relatively inexperienced to C and C++ programming, but if it is possible to load and call symbols from shared libraries (as I understand are compiled and linked much like binaries), is it also possible to load symbols from another [executable] binary during run time?

I'm particularly interested in doing this with GCC on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically yes, you should be able to pull out object from a binary and link against it ( either statically or dynamically ) but it requires you to examine the binary structure. That is easily done since modern Linux systems all use ELF binaries, which is well documented.   Suggest that you start from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are programming on Windows

1. [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load the shared library into current process
2. [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the address of the function that you want to call

On unix like Oses. something like **dlopen** and **dlsym**

[An example of dlsym](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/more-examples.html) look for 6.6. File demo_dynamic.c

Comment: Restriction: binary must be compiled as a dynamically-linkable shared object. The dynamic linker expects library name sonames and versions that are only placed during library linking as opposed to standalone executable linking.

Comment: "if it is possible to load and call symbols from shared libraries (as I understand are compiled and linked much like binaries), **is it also possible to load symbols from another binary during run time?**"

Comment: I'm afraid moshbear has the accurate interpretation of my question.

Comment: But, on the other hand, to quote the MSDN "LoadLibrary can also be used to load other executable modules. For example, the function can specify an .exe file to get a handle that can be used in FindResource or LoadResource."   ...  So we're half way there, I suppose I just need to verify the technique for linux.